# CIFilter memory leak in iOS7

Tags: ios, cifilter, ciimage

I am trying to implement the following function using `CIGloom` filter. However, I have a problem with memory leak.

I tried to run the code in both iOS7 and iOS6 devices, but the problem only seems to occur in iOS7.

```
- (CIImage*) GloomFilter : (CIImage*) sourceImage{
    id filterReleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CIImage * outputImage = sourceImage;

    float gloomRadius = 1. / 10. * outputImage.extent.size.width;

    {
        CIFilter *filter = [ CIFilter filterWithName : @"CIGloom" ];
        [ filter setDefaults ];
        [ filter setValue : [ NSNumber numberWithFloat : gloomRadius ]
                            forKey : @"inputRadius" ];
        [ filter setValue : [ NSNumber numberWithFloat : 1.0 ]
                            forKey : @"inputIntensity" ];
        [ filter setValue : outputImage 
                            forKey : kCIInputImageKey ];
        outputImage = filter.outputImage;
    }

    [ outputImage retain ];

    [ filterReleasePool release ];

    return [ outputImage autorelease ];
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?